# Angular 2 cache HTTP response to session storage

Tags: angular, caching, rxjs, session-storage

I want to cache (using session storage) the HTTP response that I'm subscribed to with RXJS. If the same request(URL) calls once again I wanted to use the session storage instead of receiving it back from the server.

I'm saving the URL as the key for session storage and server response as the value.

I'm a beginner to both Angular 2, RXJS and Observer concept wanted to know how scalable this approach is.

```
private setLoginData():void{
    this.loginDataObserver().subscribe(
        (data:any)=>{
            let loginData:LoginUser={
                id : data.employee.id,
                name : data.employee.first_name+' '+data.employee.last_name,
                jobTitle : data.employee.job_title,
                company : data.profile.name,
                avatar : data.employee.avatar,
                role : data.role
            }

        }
    );
}

private loginDataObserver(){
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})});
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('token',this.cookie.get('token'));
    options.search=params;

    if(sessionStorage.getItem(this.dataUrl+this.cookie.get('userId'))!=null){
        let cacheJson=JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(this.dataUrl+this.cookie.get('userId')));
        let cacheDataProvider : BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(cacheJson);
        let cacheObserver:Observable<any>=cacheDataProvider.asObservable();
        return cacheObserver;
    }

    return this.http.get(this.dataUrl,options).
            do((res:Response) => sessionStorage.setItem(this.dataUrl,JSON.stringify(res.json()))).
            map((res:Response) => res.json()).
            catch(this.handleError)
}
```

I'm planning to enhance this as an Angular 2 service with methods to enable cache,

Answer (score 1):

I would make three methods:

- `getUrlContentsFromCache(url) : Observable<string>`
- `getUrlContentsFromWeb(url) : Observable<string>`
- `storeInCache(url, contents) : Observable<string>`

Since Rx is lazy by default you can use `.concat` combined with `.take(1)` to prevent a successful retrieval from cache also go and fetch the contents from the web:

```
function getContents(url){
  return getUrlContentsFromCache(url)
    .concat(
      getUrlContentsFromWeb(url)
        .flatMap(content => storeInCache(url, content))
    )
    .take(1);
}
```

Comment: I'm new to RxJx I will look up the idea you have posted :) thank you

Comment: I would recommend reading around over here http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html to get a better grasp of the concepts